# Make my jQuery accordion responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

I have created this jQuery accordion and want to make it responsive on smaller screens. I know there is a way to make this responsive using CSS media query but I am wondering if there is a better way of making it responsive using JS. I am also hoping that the tabs sit on top of each other on smaller screens. Can anyone please help me.

Also please feel free to suggest anything that could improve this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var tabButton = ".allContainer .tabsList .tab-wrapper .tabButton";
 var tabButtonCurrent = ".allContainer .tabsList .tab-wrapper > .curr";
 var tabContent = ".allContainer .tabsList .tab-content .curr";
    var tabContentParent = ".allContainer .tabsList .tab-content";
 
 $(tabButton).on('click', function(){
  
  $(tabButtonCurrent).removeClass('curr');
  $(this).addClass('curr');

  var panelId = $(this).attr('rel');

  $(tabContent).hide(500, showClickedSlider);
        
  function showClickedSlider(){
  $(this).removeClass('curr');
  
  $(panelId).show(500, function(){
  $(this).addClass('curr');
  });
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.tabList {
    width:100%;
}
.tab-wrapper {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color:olivedrab;
    height:200px;
}
.tabButton {
 float:left;
 margin-right:1%;
    min-width: 50px;
    height:200px;
 background-color:orange;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.tab-content {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
}
.tab-content > div {
    display: none;
 width:350px;
}
.tab-content .curr {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allContainer">
 
 <div class="tabsList">
 
        <div class="tab-wrapper">
            <div class="tabButton curr" data-u="#tab01" rel="#tab01">tab1</div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="curr" id="tab01">content 01</div>
                </div>
        </div>
   
  
   <div class="tab-wrapper">
            <div class="tabButton" rel="#tab02">tab2</div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="tab02">content 02</div>
                </div>
        </div>
  
  
   <div class="tab-wrapper">
            <div class="tabButton" rel="#tab03">tab3</div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="tab03">content 03</div>
                </div>
        </div>
  
  
 </div>


</div>
```

Comment: CSS media query is best way for this, i don't think js is good way for making your accordion responsive

Comment: What do you mean by "tabs sit on top of each other on smaller screens"? Please elaborate.

Comment: @nidhi Yes finally fixed it with some jquery and media query